# How are properties evaluated in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, property-testing

Please read with patience, I tried my best to explain the situation, if not please comment -

I have two plugins say `A`, `B`. In both of the plugins I defined an "and" expression for a command. One of the conditions in the "and" expression is to test a property lets say `myprop`.
`A` doesn't depend on `B` and `B` doesn't depend on `A`.

There is a property tester defined in a third plugin lets say `C`. `A` , `B` both depend on `C`.

And in a fourth plugin `D`, the extension point for `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` is defined and the list of properties to be tested by tester defined in plugin `C`.

`A`, `B` depends on plugin `D` too.

I see a strange behavior in eclipse - Only when perspective defined by plugin B is active the property tester for `myprop` is called.
So when RCP starts if plugin `B` is not already active, property tester doesn't test the property `myprop` and it returns unexpected value when I am in perspective of plugin `A`.

Later when I bring up perspective of plugin `B`, the property tester tests `myprop` and the plugin `A` then starts working properly.

Question : Why the property tester needs plugin `B` to be active ? How are properties evaluated by eclipse framework, is there an order ? or actually I should ask : When and how is a property tester for a particular property triggered ? Is there any documentation about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to specify `forcePluginActivation="true"` on the `test` element of your expression as it sounds like the plugin containing the property tester has not activated by anything.

Comment: minutes before I figured out you answered it. Yes I had to specify `forcePluginActivation="true"` to make it work. But I will accept your answer. I have one question though. Is `forcePluginActivation` applied to plugin `D` where my property tester class is defined or to plugin `C` where the extension point is defined in which list of properties to be tested are specified ? I think it should have been applied to `C` because the property tester is hit for other properties.

Comment: It will be the plugin containing the tester class that is activated.

Comment: Actually it is not what I found, when I set a breakpoint in my tester class before I specified `forcePluginActivation` as `true`, the breakpoint was hit which suggests me that the plugin containing the tester class was activated already but it doesn't know about the property that plugin `D` specifies in the `propertyTester` extension.